# What is the difference between Run as php script and php web page in eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse

I am a newbie to php and have been trying to use Eclipse PDT for my php work. I have found that there are two options that I can use for a php page from eclipse pdt

```
 Run as php script and Run as php web page
```

but wondering what is the exact difference between those.

Also, I want to know if the difference is eclipse specific or an attribute of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall take a wild guess here, Run as script would  RUN from PHP Console i.e. CLI and Run as web page is pretty self explanatory